# Tablas de ancho especifico en bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap

Tengo un problema con el contenido de una columna en una tabla, mi problema es que el ancho de la tabla se ajusta al contenido haciendo que si es muy grande (me gusta como se ve en pantallas de pc, mi problema es la vista en pantallas mas chicas)
Acabe aclarar que es conjunto de "asdasdas" sigue mucho mas a la derecha solo que no puedo postear un gif o un video para hacerlo mas ilustrativo[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí], causa que la tabla se haga muy largo con un scroll feo, mi intencion es si puedo ajustar el ancho de esa columna en especifico para que cuando llegue al maximo indicado el contenido baje un renglon les dejo una imagen para que vean el scroll que se me hace

Aca dejo mi codigo (la imagen no hay que hacerle caso ya que solo se ve en pantallas mas grandes):
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][2]][2]

```
<div class="seccion">
<div class="exp-title">
    <h4>EXPERIENCIA LABORAL</h4>
    <ul class="exp-iconos">
        <li><a>
                <fa-icon [icon]="faPenToSquare" class="icono1"></fa-icon>
            </a></li>
        <li><a>
                <fa-icon [icon]="faTrashCan" class="icono1"></fa-icon>
            </a></li>
        <li (click)="MostrarFormExp()"><a>
                <fa-icon [icon]="faPlus" class="icono1" ></fa-icon>
            </a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<section class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-sm">
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let exp of experiencia">
            <td class="fotoTrabajo d-none d-md-block tabla "><img src="../../../assets/img/logo_trabajo-removebg-preview.png" class="imagen-trabajo"></td>
            <td scope="col">{{exp.nombreE}}</td>
            <td scope="col">{{exp.descrpE}}</td>
            <td scope="col">{{exp.fechaInicio}}</td>
            <td scope="col">{{exp.fechaFinal}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</section>
```

```
ul{
padding-left:1rem ;
}
.seccion{
    box-shadow: 0 0 7px rgba(0,0,0,.9);
    background:#ffffff;
    margin-top:0.625rem;
    padding: 0.9375rem;
    border-radius: 1.25rem;
}
.exp-iconos{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    list-style: none;
}
.icono1{
    color: #000000;
}
.exp-title{
    display: flex;
    justify-content:space-between;
}
.imagen-trabajo{
    max-width: 70px;
    max-height: 40px;
}
```

Comment: ¿y el código?  Con tan solo la imagen no hacemos nada aquí.  Por favor, léete [ask], [tour] y [example] para aprender el funcionamiento de este sitio y cómo elaborar buenas preguntas.

Comment: Tenes razon lo escribi a las apuradas, disculpa, ya lo adjunte en la pregunta

Comment: No soy capaz de identificar el código que has puesto (por cierto, el código lo debes poner en modo texto para poder reproducir tu error, una imagen no ayuda a ayudarte).  Es decir, no me liga el código con la imagen del problema que tienes, ¿seguro que no te has equivocado al ponerlo? Mira de hacer un [example] válido que reproduzca tu error y así la ayuda será mucho más rapida y mejor.

Comment: Capaz escatime es poner todo el codigo, ahora me voy a explayar mejor

Comment: Gracias por el consejo ya deje todo el codigo

Comment: Bueno, diría que no hay forma de "bajar un renglón" en las tablas cuando se redimensionan.  Pero quizás debas plantearte cambiar esa tabla por divs con clases **col** y **row** que sí que te bajarán el renglón al redimensionar.  Eso que has puesto en forma de tabla no tiene demasiado sentido, pues es solo un registro y no una lista (ojo, no se angular, pero acabo de ver esto: `<tr *ngFor="let exp of experiencia">` que tiene pinta de ser un bucle, je, entonces me callo :-)).